# How do I change the commit text color in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, commit, textcolor

I'm trying to change the color of the text when I'm going to commit. The color of the current text does not distinguish very well from the background color. Anyone know how to change it? Attached a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a third party theme or is this a theme that came with WebStorm?

Comment: I'm using the Darcula theme. It's a theme that comes with Webstorm.

Comment: Have you tried updating? I'm curious if that would fix the issue. I'm on the latest GA build and don't have the issue.

Comment: @EvanWieland I just updated Webstorm to the latest version, but the problem persists.